# Simple, cheap "Nano-UPS" for 5V/<2A/<10W load (e.g. IP camera), based on 4xAAA batteries (or similar)

Tags: batteries, usb, ups

There are many inexpensive IP cameras available these days, most of which run on 5VDC supplied via a USB2 cable. Problem: a power interruption of even a tenth of a second is plenty enough to force the device to restart when power returns, and risks loss of data both through a discontinuity of recording and possible corruption of a local microSD card being used as a recording medium.

Suppose we want to enable such a cam (or a similar small, low-power device) to shrug off a transient power interruption of from 0.1 to 10 seconds at least, and optionally up to 100 or 1,000 seconds, through the use of a minimalist battery backup, or "nano-UPS", which uses a quartet of ordinary AAA cells wired in series as its power reserve. Assume that the device will continue operating as long as it receives a voltage of between 4 and 6 volts. Suppose a power-loss failover starts with a fresh set of AAA batteries producing 1.5 V each, and continues operating until the four cells have each drained down to close to 1.0 V. At a steady combined load of between 2 and 10 watts (0.5 to 2.5 watts per cell), that should take several hours — much more than the few seconds (or less) that will be needed in most instances.

Suppose we wish to construct a bare-bones connection that simply keeps the 4xAAA batteries ready to supply the necessary current instantly (for practical purposes) if and when the primary voltage supply drops below a minimum level (say, 4.2 V). For simplicity, there's no need to accommodate trickle-charging the batteries from the primary supply; let's just assume that the batteries will be replaced manually when they're run down. Let's also assume that there's no need for a DC transformer to regulate the voltage supplied by the batteries; we'll just count on them being in the appropriate range.

The objective here is to be simple, reliable, and compact, so as to be easy to install behind an IP cam, and easy to protect from environmental threats (mostly moisture) when placed outdoors.
What are the minimal components needed to implement such a failover circuit as this, and how should they be assembled with a minimum of fuss (preferably without soldering)?

[For brownie points, please leave a comment if you're aware of an off-the-shelf product already available that provides this functionality, either as described here, or by a different method of similarly low cost and complexity (e.g. small LiPo). Thanks.]

Comment: I can't answer regarding commercial off-the-shelf options (no idea plus product recommendations are off-topic), but if you're willing to do PCB fabrication there are tons of "ideal diode" or "power OR" controllers that can be used; furthermore the "DC transformer" you mention is commonly available in the form of a voltage regulator. By doing some math on quiescent current consumption and battery capacity, you'll be able to conclude whether this is feasible/convenient in terms of battery lifetime.

Comment: For price and lack of soldering, it will be hard to beat a small cheap USB power bank - find one that offers simultaneous charging and supply. I use them as a UPS for a raspberry pi, etc.

Comment: @Ale..chenski The question you linked is helpful in shedding some light on my understanding of the issue, but it's not a complete resolution. In other words, it's certainly related, but not a duplicate. Please bear with me as I try to clarify my question. Thanks!

Comment: Here's another related question: [Low voltage DC Supercap UPS Design](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/137092/low-voltage-dc-supercap-ups-design)

Comment: @tomnexus: You're right, that would be a simple solution… except that I haven't been able to find a power bank meeting your description. I've tested several, and either they won't supply power to the load at all while also being charged themselves, or the transition from mains to battery still involves a brief interruption of power to the load, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. If you can recommend any specific products, I'm all ears.

Comment: @jdmc maybe I was lucky, or my Pi tolerates a small drop. I've just looked for "USB power bank pass through" and there are many for sale. Some say they have a Pass Through mode, which is slower charging than their regular mode. That sounds bad. Others seem to have a separate LiPo charger and USB power supply, which might work better. Look for comments mentioning Raspberry Pi UPS. Good luck.